# What is the point of the Thieves Guild ledger?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've recently become the Guild Master of the Thieves Guild in Skyrim, and I was wondering if the business ledger in the guild had any use outside of cosmetic purposes? I've tried using it, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These types of ledgers are used in Delvin's "Numbers Job" radiant quests.  For this type of job, you'll have to sneak into a business and interact with the ledger in order to change something, which the game generally doesn't go into any consistent detail about.

The one in the Guild proper is not one that I've ever had as a target, even though I've run  probably around 100 of these jobs.  It kind of makes sense, as editing your own ledger wouldn't make much sense.

Outside of these quests, I've not found a use for it (or any of them) - it's not referenced in any other quest that I can find, so it appears to be strictly cosmetic.

Comment: Yeah, I'm away of their use in other businesses, I was just wondering if I was missing a use for it, or if it was purely cosmetic.

Comment: @iLevin, as I mentioned in my answer (in addition to the explanation) this object appears to be strictly cosmetic.

Comment: I'm aware of that, thought I'd just add a comment saying I'm aware of the other ledgers, in case it has a hidden use that someone else is aware of, and happened to read my comment.

Comment: @iLevin That should probably be a clarifying edit to your question than a comment on an answer, then. Makes it more likely that someone will "happen" to read it. :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no, you can't change any business ledger throughout skyrim whatsoever unless you do the "Numbers job" for Delvin Mallory in the Ragged Flagon